# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'theme.spacing[radius]')

Tags: react-native, user-interface, button, shared-libraries

I am using react native elements library to build a UI. I am trying to create a button with an icon. I initially just copied this code from the website without any changes to see if the button works.

```js
import { Button } from "@rneui/themed";

<Button
              title="Basic Button"
              buttonStyle={{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 116, 289, 1)',
                borderRadius: 3,
              }}
              containerStyle={{
                width: 200,
                marginHorizontal: 50,
                marginVertical: 10,
              }}
 />
```

I keep getting this error in the app

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'theme.spacing[radius]')
```

which comes from inside Button.js that comes with the ui.library. I am not sure what could be causing this. I managed to use the input component from the library without any issues and from that I would assume I installed it properly. What could be causing this button problem then?

Comment: The problem is probably within the package. It's possible that it is not compatible in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you don't create button with touchOpacity and icon
it easier than you use library

Answer (score 11):

Import `Button` module from `@rneui/base` instead of `@rneui/themed`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. You can solve this issue by wrapping the **ThemeProvider** component from react-native-elements (@rneui) in the root of your app. For example;

```
<ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
  <Button title="My Button" />
</ThemeProvider>
```

official migration guide for react-native-elements:
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/migration_guide